# Thread, listbox y un loop infinito

Tags: c#, hilos, bucles, listbox

Intento hacer una aplicacion de escritorio de windows en C# y lo que intento hacer es tener un boton que active un thread que muestre un loop infinito en un listbox que se pueda detener con otro boton, soy nuevo en threads asi que no se como empezar.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int counter = 0;
        public bool IsRunning = false;
        public List oThreads = new List();

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ImportStart));
        //oThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        //oThread.Name = "Main Thread";
        //oThread.IsBackground = true;
        //oThread.Start();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // IsRunning = !IsRunning;


        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ImportStart));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Name = "t" + (oThreads.Count() + 1).ToString();
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();

        oThreads.Add(t);
    }

    public void ImportStart()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            // if (IsRunning)
            //{
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                //if (counter < 100)
                //    label1.Text = (counter++).ToString();
                label1.Text = oThreads.Count().ToString();

                //listBox1.Items.Add(oThreads.Count().ToString());
                //listBox1.Refresh();
                //listBox1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(ListBox1_DoubleClick);

            }));
            //   Thread.Sleep(500);
            //}
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (oThreads.Count > 0)
        {
            oThreads.Last().Abort();
            oThreads.RemoveAt(oThreads.Count() - 1);
        }
    }

    private void ListBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (oThreads.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int n = oThreads.Count() -1; n>= 0; n--)
                {
                    string removelistitem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                    {

                        oThreads.Last().Abort();
                        oThreads.RemoveAt(oThreads.Count() - 1);

                    }
                }

                //oThreads.Last().Abort();
                //oThreads.RemoveAt(oThreads.Count() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Mira la clase `backgroundworker`que creo que puede adaptarse a lo que necesitas. Si te da algun problema añade el ejemplo completo para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Saludos Jonathan y bienvenido al sitio, echale un vistazo al [tour] y [ask] para que entiendas como preguntar aquí y el funcionamiento básico del sitio, como comprenderás, no entiendo tu pregunta sin el código correspondiente que me permita identificar tu problema, recuerda agregar cualquier información útil con el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/181779/edit), saludos :)

Comment: esta basado en opiniones en cuanto al uso de threads, pero en cuanto al ciclo infinito la solución es bastante facil

Answer (score -2, accepted):

como hacer un ciclo infinito

```
 bool loop = false;
 public void IniciaMetodoInfinito(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //thread secundario 
 {
      loop = true;
      while (loop == true)
      {
      //esto se repite infinitametne
      }
 }

 public void DetieneMetodoInfinito()//thread principal
 {
      loop = false;
 }
```

ahora, para invocar el thread secundario ahi hay muchos metodos, pero creo que el mas sencillo es llamar a un backgroundWorker para que ejecute "IniciaMetodoInfinito()"

```
  click_botonIniciar()
  { 
    var worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += IniciaMetodoInfinito;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
 click_botonDetener()
 { 
   DetieneMetodoInfinito()
 }
```

Comment: gracias, no es todo lo que estaba buscando pero fuiste el unico en contestar asi que gracias

Comment: solo para añadir, no debes tratar de detener un thread, es possibles destruirlos, pero con ellos destruyes toda la instancia del thread, lo que es recomendable es que el thread pueda leer variables que puedes modificar desde la interfaz de usuario y cuando esa variable se cumple entonces inicias el proceso para que el thread llegue al final de su ejecución (si es que esta trabajando indefinidamente) si mal no recuerdo se llama "comunicacion por mensajes"

Comment: Gracias, te dejo mi codigo

Comment: Lo que pasa que lo que quiero hacer es poder con un doble click detener el item del thread que se muestra en el listbox pero cuando hago eso se detiene todo y los demas threads que ya tengo corriendo no siguen corriendo mas en el listbox